# "force allow apps on external" on EMUI 5.x not toggling on

Tags: app2sd, 7.1-nougat

so i've been trying to force allow apps on external storage by ticking the option: **force allow apps on external**
 under the developer options segment of the phone but it just doesn't seem to work. Every time I try to  toggle this setting on, it just refuses to turn on it goes back to its original greyed out state. 
Please note that I have set my Default Storage" to SD; Could this be the reason ?

Thank You,
Wael

Comment: Please note that my device is Huawei GR3 2017. I tried to switch the default storage from SD back to INTERNAL, then tried to switch the option: "force allow apps on external" but it still acting the same (the moment I move the slider to the right, it goes back to the left to its OFF state). I even tried to turn on this setting on a different Huawei model (also EMUI 5.x) the same thing happened. So I guess it's a bug with EMUI.

Comment: any updates here? i encountered this issue too

Answer (score 1):

Huawei has disabled this function. It won't work unless you root the device.

Source: Huawei support website.